# python tkinter destroy toplevel

Tags: python, tkinter

I've got a bit of a problem with the tkinter Toplevel widget. Whenever I try to destroy a toplevel window, it won't close, but instead it becomes inactive. Whenever I click the window, which should have been destroyed, I get a memoryaddress error. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Example code:

```
from tkinter import *
import _thread as thread
import time
root = Tk()
root.title('root')
login = Toplevel(root)
login.title('login')
thread.start_new_thread(root.mainloop,())
time.sleep(3)
login.destroy()
```

Comment: Don't use `time.sleep()` in asynchronous code.

Comment: Even without the `destroy` line, I get `RuntimeError: Calling Tcl from different appartment`. Seems that Tkinter doesn't play nice with threads in general.

Comment: @Kevin: you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tkinter is not thread-safe. All Tkinter calls should originate from a single thread. Use `root.after` to schedule a function call to happen after a delay.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('root')
login = Toplevel(root)
login.title('login')
root.after(3000, login.destroy)
root.mainloop()
```

Per the [TkinterSummary](http://www.astro.washington.edu/users/rowen/TkinterSummary.html):

> All Tkinter access must be from the main thread (or, more precisely,
>   the thread that called mainloop). Violating this is likely to cause
>   nasty and mysterious symptoms such as freezes or core dumps.